# Correct R syntax for changing draw() plot - gratia package

Tags: r, draw, mgcv

I need help translating "modelling the long-term trend that varies spatially in my data" and for changing the plot below into the correct R syntax.

[image]

I'd like to have Longitude on the x-axis, latitude on the y-axis, and a panel for each calendar year ("CYR"). Changing the order of the variables in my smooth function gives me this error though:

```
     ...ti(Latitude, CYR, Longitude, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'), k = c(25, 14)), ..
     ...ti(CYR, Latitude, Longitude, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'), k = c(25, 14)), ..

Error in check.term(termi, rec) : 
  bam can not discretize with this nesting structure
```

It's also somehow connected to my other covariates as well (removing them stops the error, but I can't get the plot to "draw" correctly).

```
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

m <- bam(occur ~ s(temp) + 
           sal + 
           s(DO) + 
           sed_depth + 
           water_depth + 

           s(fCYR, bs = "re") + # Long-term trend
           
           # Spatial variation
           s(Longitude, Latitude, k = 100, bs = 'tp') + # Try bs = tp (default)
           
           s(fSite, bs = "re") + # Repeated measures design
         
         # long-term trend varies spatially (code I need to change, I think)
         ti(Latitude, CYR, Longitude, d = c(2,1), bs = c('ds','tp'), k = c(25, 14)),
         
         data = toad, 
         method = 'fREML', 
         # knots = knots,
         nthreads = 4, 
         discrete = TRUE,
         family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
         # select = TRUE,
         gamma = 1.5)

draw(m, select = 6)
```

Comment: You aren't changing `d`, `bs` etc, but I don't think that's the source of the problem. Will your model run with `ti(CYR, Latitude, Longitude, d = c(1,2), bs = c("tp", "ds"), ....)`? `bam()` tries to reorder smooths to make it easier for the algorithm, so it's not possible to force this while {gratia} doesn't have a way to intuit what you want. This is a known infelicity in {gratia}: https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/issues/191 As I would like this fixed for my course in a couple of weeks I hope to get this fixed. IN the meantime I'll show how to do it manually (after my meeting)

Comment: Hi @GavinSimpson, yes, it plots with ti(CYR, Latitude, Longitude, d = c(1,2), bs = c("tp", "ds"), ....) with facets = Longitude. Do you have a link for the course as well or will it be a recording on YouTube? I hope to see it as well.

Comment: The course is here: https://www.physalia-courses.org/courses-workshops/gams-in-r/ but it's paid, so no, the video won't be on YouTube this time. Materials will be at (previous versions already there): https://github.com/gavinsimpson/physalia-gam-course

Comment: This should work automagically now using the GitHub version of {gratia} (versions 0.8.1.24 or later) as I have implemented this feature and closed #191.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! If you have time, I also had a question regarding when to use 'unconditional = FALSE' in plot.gam() or draw() - as in, how/when can a smoothing parameter be known ahead of time and not estimated from the data? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/609685/when-to-use-unconditional-false-in-plot-gam?noredirect=1#comment1131915_609685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 0.8.1.25 (the development version of the package at the time of writing), {gratia} should now be able to handle this automatically.

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

df <- data_sim("eg1", n = 1000,  dist = "normal", scale = 2, seed = 1)
m <- gam(y ~ te(x0, x1, x2, k = c(25, 10), d = c(1,2), bs = c("cr", "ds")),
         data = df, method = "REML")
draw(m, n = 25)
```

produces

[image]

which, as can be seen, has plotted the 2D Duchon spline in the panels and `x0` on the facets even though this is not how the terms were ordered when the `te()` term was defined in the formula.

Contray to my comment on the OP's question, this (`draw.gam()` behaviour) was only added in 0.8.1.25; .24 added support for `smooth_estimates()` and its `draw()` method only.

I posted this as a separate answer because this new behaviour only works for 2D marginal smooths; if we had `te(x0, x1, x2, x3, bs = c("cr", "ds"), d = c(1, 3))`, the code currently doesn't identify that we could do better by generating data for `x1` and `x2` to go on the x and y axes of the panels, and then facet by `x3` and `x1`. In that case you will still need the ideas in the original answer I posted to generate the desired output manually.

Comment: Quick question! I think the new version downloaded fine, but loading the library gave me this error...Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gratia’:object ‘case_match’ is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr' ...In addition: Warning message:
package ‘gratia’ was built under R version 4.2.3

Comment: I can't update my version of R without IT support, but maybe that's the main issue?

Comment: The error related to `case_match` means your **dplyr** is out of date. It's always best to update your installed packages with `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE, Ncpus = X)` setting `X` to as many CPU cores you want to use. Hopefully you can update packages without IT support. But note gratia needs a reasonably recent version of R (4.1.0 or later)

Comment: Last question! Is it possible to facet by a factor (label)? My facet variable was calendar year and the facet labels converted 2007 to "2008", 2008 to "2008.933", 2009 to "2009.867"..etc. I tried putting a factor version of year into the te() term, but of course it really didn't like that. I also tried it in the ggplot version, but got the same decimal results.

Comment: The only way to get a factor into a tensor product is through a random effect basis and while that works with `smooth_estimates()` I'm genuinely not sure what `draw()` will do with a random effect marginal in a tensor product. If something doesn't work out of the box, you are better off using `smooth_estimates()` plus your own ggplot code as per the previous answer, but pass `smooth_estimates()` the data slice you want to evaluate the smooth at - so you can fix the values of `year` that you want.

Comment: @Nate I added an example to the original answer showing how to do what I mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively easy to do this by hand if you know some ggplot:

```r
library("gratia")
library("mgcv")
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")

df <- data_sim("eg1", n = 1000,  dist = "normal", scale = 2, seed = 1)
m <- gam(y ~ te(x2, x0, x1, k = c(5, 20), d = c(1,2), bs = c("ds", "cr")),
         data = df, method = "REML")

sms <- smooth_estimates(m, n = 50, n_3d = 10)

est_lim <- c(-1, 1) * max(abs(sms[["est"]]), na.rm = TRUE)

sms |>
    mutate(fx2 = factor(x2)) |>
    ggplot(aes(x = x0, y = x1, fill = est, group = fx2)) +
    geom_raster(aes(x = x0, y = x1, fill = est, group = fx2)) +
    geom_contour(aes(z = est, group = fx2, fill = NULL), colour = "black") +
    facet_wrap(~ fx2) +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", type = "div") +
    expand_limits(fill = est_lim)
```

Here I'm manually identifying that the second smooth in the example is a 2d spline, so I know to plot `x0` and `x1` on the x and y axes of the plot.

That code produces

[image]

It's trickier to do this in the package code, so that it happens automatically, and writing an interface to that if there are no hints in the model (no 2d smooths) and you want to be able to specify what gets plotted where is harder still. I think I'll have the former (identify a 2d smooth and plot that on the x and y axes, facetting on the other variables) available in {gratia} shortly, but the harder part will need more thinking and likely won't be doable directly from a `draw(m)` like command.

For complete control (e.g. to specify specific [pretty] values for `x2` for the facets), generate a data slice of the values you want to evaluate the smooth at:

```r
ds <- data_slice(m, x0 = evenly(x0, n = 50), x1 = evenly(x1, n = 50),
                 x2 = seq(0, 1, by = 0.25))
sms <- smooth_estimates(m, data = ds)
est_lim <- c(-1, 1) * max(abs(sms[["est"]]), na.rm = TRUE)

sms |>
    ggplot(aes(x = x0, y = x1, fill = est, group = x2)) +
    geom_raster(aes(x = x0, y = x1, fill = est, group = x2)) +
    geom_contour(aes(z = est, group = x2, fill = NULL), colour = "black") +
    facet_wrap(~ x2) +
    scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdBu", type = "div") +
    expand_limits(fill = est_lim)
```

which produces

[image]